# What sets are these vintage figures and wheels from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, minifigure-identification

[image]

Where do these belong to? (their head/body/hair/hat might be mixed up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the parts you're looking for:

[wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3137c01assy1#T=C)

[wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3137c02assy1#T=C)

[2x4 wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4180c02assy1#T=C)

[wheel base 2x4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4180c02&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) and so on

[arm holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=792c03&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[hand](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3614a&idColor=3#T=C&C=3)

[arm part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3612&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[also arm part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3613&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[female hair](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x196&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[head with freckles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=685px3&idColor=3#T=C&C=3)

[cap](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0015&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

Based on the collected links, this might be one of the sets you own. It is too challenging for me to identify any others, sorry for the inconvenience: [https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=200-1#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=200-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: I can't combine them and identify a particular set out of hte heads and hat combinations I have unfortunately.

Comment: @Lotte I'll give it a shot, I 'll use the links I have and try to see if they can be smashed together to form complete sets. It might not be possible however since we don't see your other parts, but let's not go too far with this vintage-identification business.

Comment: @Lotte I could only find one possible set, at least I tried.

Answer (score 1):

The red cap is fairly unusual. The head with the freckles as well...
Based on that I would say the Universal Building set 50-1 [on BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=50-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
The rightmost wheels are in that set too. The other wheels are so common that there are dozens of sets with them.